# Android - restrict space to take match_parent and views on both sides

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a horizontal linearLayout including a TextView, an EditText and another EditText.
Both TextViews are set to wrap_content in width and heigth. The EditText has wrap_content in height and match_parent in width.

My goal is to get those three views in one line filling the whole line.
But with the above written settings, I have the first TextView taking up the needed space and the EditText filling the rest, not keeping free space for the other TextView.

I achieved a temporary solution by setting layout_weight of both TextViews to 0 and of the EditText to 500 which I'm sure is not the real solution.

Edit: current layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gewicht:"
        android:id="@+id/lblWeight"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="60"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"

        android:layout_weight="500"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblUnitWeight"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="g." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid `layout_weight` property? Because your are already using it. What do you want to change above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit consufed, but is this what you want?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftTextView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rightTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this, it should works fine.

Comment: Small change: you only need the `+` in `@+/id` whenever you are referencing a view for the first time.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, but now, the edittext is a bit lower than the textviews. How can that be fixed?

Comment: I think `LinearLayout` is better suited for the desired design.

Comment: You can add centerInVertical="true" to each child view

Comment: @MaskedMan I thought so first, too. But with that approach I can't get it to work on full width without linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight to determine width of each views. Update the weight values according to your need.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gewicht:"
        android:id="@+id/lblWeight"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="60"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"

        android:layout_weight="500"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblUnitWeight"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="g." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! So I think the thing I was missing is to set the width to 0dp.

Comment: But I still have something mussing. I want the layout to use the full width, and if I set the weight of the EditText to a higher value, it moves the first TextView to use 2 lines.

Comment: You can use android:ems property to each views to have at least a minimum size width-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gewicht:"
        android:id="@+id/lblWeight"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="60"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
        android:layout_weight="500"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblUnitWeight"
        android:textColor="@color/mainForeground"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="g." />

</LinearLayout>
```